# Run a code snippet before and after tests with testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I have a set of R functions which get called from a Ruby application and would like to test them. The R functions access data from a Postgres database so to write tests I need to populate a test database with some sample data.

I would like to avoid cleaning up the database within every test case. It would be nice if I could start a transaction before every test and rollback the transaction after.

The last paragraph of the "Writing Tests" section of this page http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html makes me think that it's not possible to execute a block of code before every test case.

Does anyone know of any creative work arounds? I'm considering forking the project and adding the functionality but wanted to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I assume you are using `RPostgreSQL`?  If so, what is stopping you from using the `dbRollback` function at the end of each test function?  It is difficult to say much more without either seeing your package or some example code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am using RPostgreSQL and you're right I could add dbRollback to the end of all of my tests. I was just hoping  I could have this done automatically for all tests since I'll be rolling back for almost every test.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, I ended up creating a wrapper function for test_that() which I use when getting data from postgres. Below is my solution:

```
db.test_that <- function(description, test_code) {
    dbGetQuery(database_connection, 'BEGIN TRANSACTION')

    test_that(description, test_code)

    dbRollback(database_connection)
}
```